# Groovy validation problem

Tags: validation, groovy

I have a groovy system configured using tomcat and Oracle 10g.
I have a groovy class which defines an follows: (reduced version)

```
class ChangeTicket {

static constraints = {
    chngNr(nullable:false) 
}

String chngNr
}
```

My controller has defined a save method:

```
 if (changeTicketInstance.validate() && !changeTicketInstance.hasErrors() && changeTicketInstance.save()) {         
        flash.message = "changeTicket.created"
        ...
    }
```

As far as I know the **save** method calls by default the validate method in order to
know if the constraints are fullfilled or not therefore the validate method call **is** redundant. Anyway, when the save is performed an exception will be thrown if the field chngNr is NULL. 
In fact the field cannot be empty (NULL) because I've defined the constraint (nullable:false).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

chngName(blank:false,nullable:false)

:-)

Answer (score 3):

The validate call should fail if **chngNr** is **NULL**.  Some databases do not consider an empty string ("") null (HSQL).  If you are binding **chngNr** to **changeTicketInstance** using params from a form it is getting assigned an empty string as a value and in that case you would want your constraint to be:

```
chngNr(blank:false)
```

Also, save() wont throw an Exception unless you use save(flush:true).  Hibernate queues up the changes and, unless you flush, wont throw an actual exception.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem has been solved adding an extra constraint blank:false. +1